# How to monitor 12 V LiPo charging from Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, battery

What's the safest way to determine a lithium-ion polymer battery's discharge and charging state using an Arduino?

I see a ton of 12 V LiPo batteries like [**this**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-4000mAh-Lithium-ion-Super-Rechargeable-Battery-Pack-AC-Charger-SPC-2369-US-/370921997007) being sold on eBay and elsewhere.

[image]

They have a built-in charger, and I'd like to use one to power an Arduino, but the Arduino needs to know "when" the battery needs to be charged, and "when" the battery is fully charged. Unfortunately, the battery doesn't expose any pins or LEDs or other outputs that I could tap into.

I've found a few LiPo charging circuits specifically designed for the Arduino, but they all can only handle 3.7 V cells.

I'd like to avoid having to disassemble the battery or modify it to allow me to monitor its state. Is there an easier way, like connecting a battery lead to an analog pin and measuring voltage, or using a coulomb counter?

Comment: You can use 2 resistors to form a voltage divider, and safely measure the battery voltage using an analog pin.

Comment: I ASSUME they use an internal converter or regulator. 4 LIPO = 12V to 16.8V. 3 LIPO = 9V to 12.6V. ANY LIPO charger worth it's salt will charge the unloaded battery until full then stop. If it does not it's dangerous rubbish. | [**Something like this gives you access**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nice-Mini-Portable-DC-168-12V-Rechargeable-Li-ion-Battery-Pack-for-CCTV-Camera/390984245269?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D27706%26meid%3D3ea5c3e9837744718087f2448aed93d4%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D6%26rkt%3D6%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D370921997007&rt=nc)

Comment: Resistor divider allow current monitoring. If quiescent drain matters a high side transistor can turn off divider and a low side transistor drives the high side. 3 resistors and 2 transistors plus divider.

Comment: @Gerben, I'm not sure that'll reliably work in this case. It might work when the battery is unplugged from the charger, but when plugged in, the voltage will probably spike to 12V even if the battery isn't fully charged yet.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I agree, but I'm not concerned about the built-in charger being at fault. For my application, the device needs to take action depending on battery state. e.g. notify the user over wifi when charging is complete or when it needs to be charged.

Comment: @Cerin It will indeed only be reliable to measure battery-charge, while not charging.

Comment: @Cerin  Note my point above that you are **probably** dealing with a boost converter's  output  - if so the 12V will give minimal to no indication of battery state of charge or when charging is complete. ie you are trying to interpret battery state from the behaviour of a boost converter whose characteristics vary by manufacturer and/or wind direction. If you used ones like I linked to that have an separate low voltage power supply you could add a low-side sense resistor and easily monitor charging. This requires no battery pack modification. At worst an adaptor between plug pack and battery.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I don't understand. The battery I linked to likely does **not** have a boost converter. Google it. People have disassembled them. They're just 3 * 3.7V cells wired in series. The "12V" in the title is a misnomer, and most descriptions claim it'll output somewhere between 10-12V. Also, the product you linked to appears to be almost identical to the one I linked to, just at a lower mAh rating. When charging, won't the output cable will always read 12V, even if the battery is nearly depleted, since the power's then coming from an external source, making divider meaingless?

Comment: @Cerin The extra information is useful - providing it initially would have helped, and copying it into the question now would be a good idea. The photo you showed adumbrated that a mains AC power cord was the input. If it's the same as mine, and if it contains 3 x LiPo cells, then a complete solution is easy. | For voltage monitoring use a divider as I suggested above. | For charge monitoring use a low side sense resistor (as above). This allows you to measure CURRENT by dropping a small voltage across it. | And, no, charge voltage when fully 'flat' will start at 9V and rise to 12.6V max ...

Comment: ... all at constant current (if the charger is any good at all) and will then taper to a reduced current and then stop charging. The transition from "some current" to "no current" signals end of charge. | Summary: Resistor divider of battery voltage to get V in ADC range. If desired a high side switch to turn off divider. Charging can be by monitoring a low side current sense resistor (some minor complications need addressing) OR charge will be easy enough to spot by watching battery voltage when charge terminates. A high side transistor can probably be used to detect some/no charge current.

Comment: The above could be made an answer with circuit etc if it was clear it would be worth the effort (attitude, not rep) and if all information was provided. The original "They have a built in charger" was wrong and majorly misleading. They have an external ~= 12V charger and that makes a vast difference. ... | The info re "~= contains 3 x LiPo cells, people have opened them" makes a vast difference too. Answer can only be as good as information available and the better the question the easier it is to give good answers.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Interesting. But what do you mean by "low side current sense resistor"? I understand what that is, but doesn't that  require a differential amplifier in order to measure the voltage drop? Is that another component I'd have to add or is there anything built-in to an Arduino that could fill the role? Sorry for the earlier confusion. And yes, this would be better placed in an answer :)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Also, if the true battery voltage can be measured while charging (and I'm still not completely convinced that'll be the case), then why would you want to also measuring current flow to determine when charging is over? Couldn't that be determined by battery voltage? e.g. if Vbatt=12.1V then charging is probably complete.

Comment: [**... (and I'm still not completely convinced that'll be the case)...**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3288/russell-mcmahon) ... ie nothing ever needs to be taken on faith, but if you do not want to take the advice as is you can easily do some web research to persuade yourself one way or the other.

Comment: Last try: Read this page from Battery University on [**Charging Lithium Ion batteries**](http://www.batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries) . Understand what it says about battery terminal voltage during CC (constant current) and CV (constant voltage) stages. Confirm as much as you wish from any reputable topically related site that this is THE standard way to charge LiIon (and LiPo are functionally identical). 
| Read what I've written above in the light of what you have learned **OR** hold whatever theories you wish re spiking to 12V etc. Which would be a  shame.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Thank you. That link answered my question. I didn't realize that lipo voltage doesn't accurately reflect the battery's charging state, while current flow does. Although I'm still not sure how to easily measure this with an Arduino.

Comment: In the CC mode (1st stage of charge up to 70%+- (see their chart) the voltage is a good measure of charge. When you reach CV mode (usually 4.2V/cell) the V is constant and I tails UNDER BATTERY CONTROL until terminated by the charger at K x Imax where K is a design decision (see their page) but from 50% to 10% usually. 50% gives long life and slightly lower capacity. 10% give noticeably shorter cycle life and  slightly higher capacity. Stopping when V =just reaches 4.2V gives say 70%-80% of capacity but much greater cycle life. ...

Comment: ...  If you put a very small resistor in ground lead of battery you can tell when the charger suddenly cuts off.Voltage drop must be very small. A Hall sensor can do this at minimal V drop or a resistor with mV range drop. Arduino 5V ADC 10 bits is about 5 mV/bit so a 50 mV drop at full current is detectable. ie need to allow say 5 counts to be safish as 0.0 V  will not read 0 count on ADC. There are other ways. .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, So if I'm using a voltage divider to measure the battery's voltage, I could also use that to detect current drop/charge completion by detecting a very small voltage drop?

Comment: Note that what you hav suggested re charge completion is not what I suggested. The answer to what you suggest is maybe/probably.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to buy something off the shelf that will provide power for an Arduino, try a power bank - they have USB out, and are also charged via USB. I found that I had to put a 100 Ohm resistor to stop mine going to sleep, but it's +5V native.

A 100 ohm resistor (0.25 watt at least!) draws 50mA, so a 5200mAH powerbank like http://www.dx.com/p/universal-5200mah-external-li-ion-battery-charger-power-bank-w-led-indicator-usb-cable-pink-362725#.VQneCnWjlIc would leak it empty in 104 hours. If you use at least 50mA at all times, then this isn't needed - I think an Arduino draws 35mA already, so you should get away with a 300 Ohm resistor, drawing 16mA. Some experimentation might be needed.

Comment: But again...these don't allow you to monitor the battery. Also, your link is to a case, not a battery...

Comment: Fixed link to point to battery, not case. You might be able to hack it, since it obviously has a monitor in there; at least you'd be able to pick up the status lights.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 10V zener diode. Check it’s voltage drop, and use that in your analogRead logic.

Get the full voltage with a DMM, and also the low cut-off voltage.